# Python Method is not overriding

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to override a python method from Odoo but getting no success in that.

for that what I am doing is

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class MYBaseModel(models.BaseModel):
    _register = False

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        print "My Method called"
        return super(MYBaseModel, self).unlink()
```

What I wanted to achieve is when the unlink method is executed by the odoo framework, my method should be called,

but right now my method is not getting called, and I don't know the reason. can anyone show me what I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

My Goal is to call **Unlink** method for all the models. so in any model the record is deleted my method should be called and then the base method should be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `_register_hook` method
For more detail and example check the file from Addons.

./addons/base_action_rule/models/base_action_rule.py

Comment: That's called a genius answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have written the function correct, but miss to add `_inherit` in your class.
Here is what you need to do, you need to add [_inherit='object.name'](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/object_inherit.html/#object-inheritance-inherit) in your `Class MYBaseModel`.

instead of `super(MYBaseModel, self).unlink()` call `models.BaseModel.unlink()` but that will skip all unlink() extensions for your model.

Comment: you are correct, but in this case I am trying to inherit odoo base model, and I wanted to modify the base unlink method.

Comment: It is none, I am not creating or inheriting any model, I am overriding odoo base unlink method.

Comment: but my question is I am simply inheriting the BaseModel class, it should override the unlink generally. why my overridden method is not getting called?

Comment: @AlphaGeek :you were using `super(MYBaseModel, self).unlink()` it will call the method from your model, you need to override it so `models.BaseModel.unlink()`, hope this has clear your doubts.

Comment: yes, I get you but, the problem is when I delete the record it should call my method and print "My Method called" which is not working right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `_inherit` property like this:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class MYBaseModel(models.BaseModel):
    _register = False
    _inherit = 'my.base.model'

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        print "My Method called"
        return super(MYBaseModel, self).unlink()
```

**EDIT:**

```
import odoo.models.BaseModel as base
class newClass(base):
    def unlink(self):
        # your code
        return super(newClass, self).unlink()
```

Comment: Nice, I got your point: you need to add a Python inheritance not an Odoo inheritance:
    
    import odoo.models.BaseModel as base

Answer (score 0):

As Surajano said in its answer,

What you did for now is defining a new BaseModel. But for now, no any magic will make it works on existing models.

**You have 2 options (at least):**

1- override existing models by python-inheriting them with `MyBaseModel` : (Surajano suggestion)

```
from odoo.addons.your_addon.models import MYBaseModel
class AccountInvoice(MYBaseModel):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    # now, invoices (and only them) will benefit or your override
```

2- Otherwise, you could do a monkey-patch :

```
odoo.models.BaseModel.unlink = MYBaseModel.unlink
# or even this : odoo.models.BaseModel = MYBaseModel, but i'm not really sure it will work
```

It will be available for every Odoo models, but this approach is bit more "definitive"

(**EDIT**: i'm not sure, but you may need to keep a trace of the original unlink method before monkey-patching it, and using this original_method in your unlink() override)

Hope it helps you,

Comment: I know the odoo's _inherit. but I wanted to call my unlink method for all odoo  models. this is the reason I am inheriting BaseModel.

Comment: That's exactly what i was saying ^^
There is no direct method to publish your new Class to the existing Odoo models (they already have been defined with the legacy BaseModel).

That's why i pointed you 2 ways to re-apply your own modification, either model per model (1st option) or for all the odoo models (2nd option, which may be what you need).

Could you try monkey-patch and tell me if it helps you ?

Answer (score 0):

try using the following Code:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class MYBaseModel(models.Model):
    _register = False
    _inherit = "ir.model"

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        print "My Method called"
        return super(MYBaseModel, self).unlink()
```